# How to query table from Binary(32) column using SHA2_256 hashed data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I have a table with a Binary(32) column to store hashed value.
When I'm trying to query the hashed column it returns no results

For the below example how to use COL_HASHED in where clause?
Below both tries failed to return result.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (Iden INT IDENTITY (1,1), COL_HASHED BINARY(32))

INSERT INTO #TEST
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','test')

--try1
SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE COL_HASHED = '0x9F86D00000000000002FEAA0C55AD015A3BFXXXXXXXXXX2CD15D6C15B0F00A08'

--try2
SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE COL_HASHED = CAST('0x9F86D00000000000002FEAA0C55AD015A3BFXXXXXXXXXX2CD15D6C15B0F00A08' as BINARY(32))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COL_HASHED` is binary, and you are saying "show me the rows where this binary value matches this string value that looks like a string representation of a binary value."

You can either compare it to a binary value (no string delimiters):

```
SELECT * FROM #TEST 
  WHERE COL_HASHED = 0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08;
```

Or you can convert your string literal, but you need `convert` with style number 1 (which says just take this string literal and pretend it's binary), not `cast`, which actually tries to convert the string *again* to binary.

```
SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE COL_HASHED = CONVERT
  (binary(32), '0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08', 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ea6fe3655c23d9e34c33312caeb5aa1)